# 【ASP.NET MVC5 VB】 Cannot use Scaffolding with error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using a translation tool.
I was working with the official Microsoft documentation, but an error occurred during the process.
The documentation says it's in C#, so I'm writing the code for it in VB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

I have set up the data model and connected it to the database, and after bringing up the Scaffolding screen and pressing Add, an error occurred.
I'm having trouble creating a controller.

Please let me know what to do.

[Add a controller 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv8MD.jpg)
[Add a controller 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xj4h.jpg)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq8s3.jpg)

【Error message (translated)】
Error
An error occurred while running the selected code generator.
Unable to get metadata for "quot_System.MvcSupplier.Models.Supplier". 
The sequence does not contain any matching elements.

Models/Supplier.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
Imports System.Data.Entity

Namespace MvcSupplier.Models
    Public Class Supplier
        Public Property Id As Integer
        <Column("仕入先コード", TypeName:="varchar(10)")>
        Public Property SupplierCode As String
    End Class
    Public Class MvcSupplierContext
        Inherits DbContext
        Public Property Suppliers As DbSet(Of Supplier)
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MvcSupplierContext" connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SupplierDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are telling it to use `quot_System.MvcSupplier.Models.Supplier`. In fact you have `MvcSupplier.Models.Supplier`.

Comment: Thanks for your message.
After I wrote the question, I tried everything and finally was able to fix the error!

Comment: What should I do after the problem is solved?
This is my first time using this site, so I don't know much about it yet!

Comment: If it was a silly typo, delete the question. If it was an actual problem, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me.
I'll have to wait two days for my answer to be accepted, so I'll leave it at that for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify the number of digits for a data type, use MaxLength().
Note that you cannot specify the number of digits by writing it in Column(TypeName := "").

```
<Column("仕入先コード", TypeName:="varchar"), MaxLength(10)>
```